# Procession and Throne room interaction

Tags: dominion, dominion-dark-ages

What happens when I play Procession and use Throne Room as an action card affected by Procession?

Let me give you an example. I have a hand of:

- Procession
- Throne room
- Bridge
- Village
- Silver

I play Throne room within Procession and then:

1. Do I play only one action card in Throne room, e.g. Bridge, and it is played 4 times (Throne room played twice, both with Bridge inside) or
2. Do I play two action cards in Throne room, e.g. I use Bridge in first play of Throne room and then Bridge is used and when I play Throne room for the second time I have to use Village (my only action card left)?

In other words: does Procession treat an action card in Throne room as one card (as we usually do when we play Throne room) or not?

Comment: I don't have Dark Ages so I can't check its rules specifically, but I think all that would happen is the normal [Throne Room / Throne Room interaction](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/936/2730) (King's Court in that case); I don't think the "trash it" part of the Procession changes anything.

Comment: I'm going to go a step further and simply suggest that this is a duplicate of the question about two King's Courts. The card text is essentially the same: "(You may) choose an Action card from your hand. Play it (three times/twice)." for King's Court/Throne Room, vs "You may play an Action card from your hand twice." So you do the same thing you do with King's Court or Throne Room, and then you do some other stuff that Procession says to do. ("Do what it says on the card, in the order it says to do it.")

Comment: Considering that Throne Room is NOT a "may" ability whereas King's Court and Procession both are, I don't think this is a duplicate.

Comment: The second edition added the may to the Throne room

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Procession rules state:

> If you Procession a Procession, you will play one Action twice, trash
>   it, gain an Action card costing more, then play another Action twice,
>   trash it, gain an Action card costing more, then trash the Procession
>   and gain an Action costing more than it.

There is no reason to assume that Throne Rooming a Procession would behave any differently: they both allow you to "play an Action card from your hand twice".

So your second scenario is correct: you would play two different action cards twice, not one action card four times over.

Comment: This is absolutely correct. You will play Procession and choose Throne Room. So you play TR twice. The first time you play TR, you must choose an action card from your hand and play it twice. That's your Bridge. Now you play TR a second time, and must choose an action card from your hand to play twice. Only Village is left, so Village it is. Now you've finished Procession's instruction to play an Action twice, so you now move on to the remaining instructions on the Procession.

Comment: Coincidentally, it's better to play the Village before the Bridge since you may draw an action with one of the two draws.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of whether you throne room your procession, or procession your throne room, you'll play the bridge and village twice if you play them. Some key things to note:

- If you Throne Room first you will play Procession twice, trashing both the village (getting a 4 cost) and bridge ( getting a printed 5 cost card, see below.)
- If you Procession the throne room, you will play the village and bridge twice, and then trash the throne room (getting a printed 5 cost card, see below.)
- Bridge's effect will go off twice, reducing the cost of all cards by two, but this is largely irrelevant, unless you play a BUNCH of bridges, or procession something really cheap like Poor House (cost 1). If you do manage to play enough bridges, to reduce the processioned card to cost 0 you'll then trash it for something costing 1, which can get wacky if you play enough bridges.
- You do not have to reveal your hand but only procession includes a "you may" clause. If you Throne room your procession you don't have to play the bridge or village if you don't want to. You could throne room your procession, playing procession twice for no effect if you wanted. However if you Procession your throne room, you would have to play 2 action cards twice for throne rooms effect.

Comment: Technically speaking, it isn't entirely true that you must play Bridge twice after playing Village twice. You fully resolve Village, which might cause you to draw into other action cards.

Comment: Uh... see point 4. You don't have to play either of the cards. Were I in that situation, I probably would village first and hope to draw something else exciting to play twice.

Comment: If you Procession your Throne Room, as opposed to the other way around, your 4th point is incorrect. You DO have to play an action twice when the Throne Room is played. You cannot choose to play no action with it, because Throne Room does not say "may". Although it doesn't tell you to reveal your hand to prove you have no actions, that doesn't mean you can "get away with it." If you play no action after playing Throne Room, but you had an action in your hand, that's cheating.

Comment: @Gendolkari I suspect that's why subsequent cards added the "may" -  with throne room there's the opportunity for cheating, so it was either that or add "reveal your hand".

Comment: 4th point updated in light of the fact that procession is a "may" ability while throne room is not.

Comment: @Jefromi You are definitely correct. The game designer has discussed this several times. He intended for all cards that force you to do something to keep you accountable, like Beaurocrat, but missed it on Throne Room and a couple others. This is indeed why King's Court is "may."